# How to simulate data of a random intercept effect model in R?

Tags: r, self-study, simulation, random-effects-model, intercept

I want to simulate data of the following random intercept effect model in R
$$Y_{ij}=\alpha+\beta x_{ij}+u_{0,i}+\epsilon_{ij}$$
$$u_{0,i} \sim N(0,\tau^2)$$
$$\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$

Here the intercept $\alpha=10$ and slope $\beta=5$, and I know $\tau=10,\sigma=1$.

**I wonder how to simulate the data of this model in R?** I found some tutorials online but they were not that helpful.

Edit: I forgot to mention that there are 20 individuals and 25 observations for each individual!

Comment: This is a hierarchical model. One starts with the upper layers, ie simulating the $\epsilon_{ij}$ and $u_{0,i}$'s, and continues with the lower layers, ie simulating the $Y_{ij}$'s. In case the $x_{ij}$ are not fixed, they should be simulated as well, from an arbitrary distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly straightforward.

One way to express a random intercept model is in matrix notation like

$$ y = X\beta + Zu$$

Here, $X$ is a design matrix, $\beta$ are regression coefficeints, $Z$ is an indicator matrix for group membership, and $u$ are the random effects.

Using R, this made really easy for your problem

```
a = 10
b = 5
beta = c(a, b)
j = rep(1:10, 10)
x = rnorm(length(j))
tau = 10
sigma = 1

X = model.matrix(~x)
Z = model.matrix(~factor(j)-1)
u = rnorm(ncol(Z), 0, tau)
eps = rnorm(length(j), 0, sigma)

y = X %*% beta + Z %*% u  + eps
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is no info on the group membership here. How did you set $Z$? I feel like it shouldn't work this way. Can you elaborate?(btw I edited the question: there are 20 individuals and 25 observations for each individual!)

Comment: @user10386405  Well...it does work this way.  The variable `j` houses the IDs for subjects.  There are 10 subjects observed 10 times (if you want to use 20 subejcts observed 25 times then do `j=rep(1:20, 25)`).  $Z$ is then an indicator matrix telling me which subject is being observed. The columns correspond to subejcts, the rows to observations.  So if subject $j$ is the $i^{th}$ observation then $Z_{i, j} = 1$.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Xi'an indicates, start with the upper levels.  Simulate the random intercepts for each group, $u_{0,i}$.  The rnorm(∙) function will work.

Next, you want to generate the $x_{i,j}$ values and the residual error terms at the lowest level.  I recommend you make sure these are uncorrelated (as this is an assumption of the model).

The easiest way to do this is to generate two random variables $x$ and $\varepsilon^*$.  Run a regression predicting $\varepsilon^*$ from $x$, and then retain the residuals from this regression.  These can be your $\varepsilon$ terms (and they will random and uncorrelated with $x$).

This is most easily done using rnorm(∙) as above, and then something like

`var.eps <- lm(var.eps ~ x)$resid`

Now you can use these values to generate your dependent variables.